# Formatting a SOCK_RAW with UDP transport to query NTP

Tags: c, sockets, ntp

I want to query an NTP server using specifically raw sockets.  This is what I have after some time, but my response is decoded to 12/31/1899.  I think I have the structures correct but am messing up how I'm passing my memory around.  (I'm running this in Ubuntu VM on Windows.  I do run the program as root in the VM).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>


#define LI(packet)   (uint8_t) ((packet.li_vn_mode & 0xC0) >> 6)
#define VN(packet)   (uint8_t) ((packet.li_vn_mode & 0x38) >> 3)
#define MODE(packet) (uint8_t) ((packet.li_vn_mode & 0x07) >> 0)

void goFail( char* msg ) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

unsigned short checkSum(unsigned short *buf, int nwords) {
        unsigned long sum;
        for(sum=0; nwords>0; nwords--) {
             sum += *buf++;
        }
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
        sum += (sum >> 16);

        return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}

struct ipheader {
 unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
 unsigned char      iph_tos;
 unsigned short int iph_len;
 unsigned short int iph_ident;
 unsigned char      iph_flag;
 unsigned short int iph_offset;
 unsigned char      iph_ttl;
 unsigned char      iph_protocol;
 unsigned short int iph_chksum;
 unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
 unsigned int       iph_destip;
};

struct udpheader {
 unsigned short int udph_srcport;
 unsigned short int udph_destport;
 unsigned short int udph_len;
 unsigned short int udph_chksum;

};

int main()   {
  printf("\nStarted...");
  fflush(stdout);

  char* host_name = "pool.ntp.org";
  char* source_name = "174.44.196.123";


  typedef struct {
    uint8_t li_vn_mode;
    uint8_t stratum;
    uint8_t poll;
    uint8_t precision;

    uint32_t rootDelay;
    uint32_t rootDispersion;
    uint32_t refId;

    uint32_t refTm_s;
    uint32_t refTm_f;
    uint32_t origTm_s;
    uint32_t origTm_f;

    uint32_t rxTm_s;
    uint32_t rxTm_f;
    uint32_t txTm_s;
    uint32_t txTm_f;
  } ntp_packet;


//  ntp_packet ntp_data_packet;// = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
//  memset( &ntp_data_packet, 0, sizeof( ntp_packet ) );
//  *( ( char * ) &ntp_data_packet + 0 ) = 0x1b;

  int raw_sock;

  //TODO what buffer size??
  char buffer[sizeof(ntp_packet) + sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader)];
  memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));


  struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) &buffer[0];
  struct udpheader *udp = (struct udpheader *)  (&buffer[0] + sizeof(struct ipheader));
  ntp_packet *ntp_data_packet = (ntp_packet*)&buffer + sizeof (struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader);

    printf("\nsizeof ip %d",sizeof(*ip));
    printf("\nsizeof ud %d",sizeof(*udp));
    printf("\nsizeof nt %d",sizeof(*ntp_data_packet));
    printf("\nsizeof buf %d\n",sizeof(buffer));

  ntp_data_packet->li_vn_mode = 0x1b;




  struct sockaddr_in sin, din;
  int one = 1;
  const int *val = &one;

  //TODO another size
//  memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof (sizeof(ntp_packet)));

  // Create a raw socket with UDP protocol

  raw_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);

  if(raw_sock < 0) {
      goFail("Socket() error");
  }

  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  din.sin_family = AF_INET;

  sin.sin_port = htons(613);
  din.sin_port = htons(123);

  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_name);
  din.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);

  ip->iph_ihl = 5;
  ip->iph_ver = 4;
  ip->iph_tos = 16; // Low delay
  ip->iph_len = sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader) +sizeof(ntp_packet) ;
  ip->iph_ident = htons(6130);
  ip->iph_ttl = 255; // hops
  ip->iph_protocol = 17; // UDP
  ip->iph_sourceip = inet_addr(source_name);
  ip->iph_destip = inet_addr(gethostbyname(host_name));

  udp->udph_srcport = htons(613);
  udp->udph_destport = htons(123);
  udp->udph_len = htons(sizeof(struct udpheader) + sizeof(ntp_packet));

  ip->iph_chksum = checkSum((unsigned short *)&ntp_data_packet, sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader));

//  if(setsockopt(raw_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0) {
//      goFail("setSockOpt() error");
//  }

  printf("...Using raw socket and UDP protocol...");

//  int wrresponse = write( sd, ( char* ) &packet, sizeof( ntp_packet ) );
//  int read_response = read( sd, ( char* ) &packet, sizeof( ntp_packet ) );

  printf("\nBefore send\n");
  for(int i =0; i<sizeof (buffer);i++) {
      if (i%16==0) {
          printf("\n");
      }
          printf("%x ",buffer[i] & 0xff);

  }



  if( sendto(raw_sock, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
    goFail("sendto() error");
  }



  printf("\nBefore read: %d",ntp_data_packet->txTm_s);



  printf("...Sendto() is OK...");
//  int n = read( raw_sock, ( char* ) buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
  int n = recv(raw_sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
  printf("\nAfter read with result %d\n",n);
  for(int i =0; i<sizeof (buffer);i++) {
      if (i%16==0) {
          printf("\n");
      }
          printf("%x ",buffer[i] & 0xff);

  }
  printf("...Got a packet!...");
  fflush(stdout);

  if ( n <= 0 ) {
    goFail( "couldnt read from socket" );
  }

    printf("\nAfter read: %d\n",ntp_data_packet->txTm_s);

  ntp_data_packet->txTm_s = ntohl( ntp_data_packet->txTm_s );
  ntp_data_packet->txTm_f = ntohl( ntp_data_packet->txTm_f );

      printf("\nAfter format: %d\n",ntp_data_packet->txTm_s);

  time_t txTm = ( time_t ) ( ntp_data_packet->txTm_s - 2208988800ull );
  printf( "DECODED RAW: The time is: %s", ctime( ( const time_t* ) &txTm ) );

  close(raw_sock);

  return 0;
}
```

(I'm aware I can just use a SOCK_DGRAM, but this exercise is to explore raw sockets).

Output

```
Program output:
Started...
sizeof ip 24
sizeof ud 8
sizeof nt 48
sizeof buf 80
...Using raw socket and UDP protocol...
Before send

5 4 10 0 50 0 17 f2 0 0 0 0 ff 11 a6 d5
ae 2c c4 7b ff ff ff ff 2 65 0 7b 0 38 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Before read: 3681606...Sendto() is OK...
After read with result 69

45 0 0 45 4a 5f 40 0 40 11 f2 12 7f 0 0 1
7f 0 0 35 94 ec 0 35 0 31 fe 78 6d 6 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 70 6f 6f 6c 3 6e 74
70 3 6f 72 67 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 29 4 b0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...Got a packet!...
After read: 3681606

After format: 1177368576
DECODED RAW: The time is: Fri Apr 23 17:49:36 1937
```

Comment: Why do you need raw sockets for NTP?

Comment: Homework + poking.

Comment: Ah, so just for experimentation. Fair enough, though when facing technical issues like this don't forget the simplest version is usually easier to debug.

Comment: Do you know the raw value of the fields you're receiving prior to decoding? Are you sure you're looking in the right spot?

Comment: It looks like you're reading into `buffer` and then using `ntp_data_packet`, which is a completely unrelated structure, to decode. Shiouldn't you read into that, or at least copy `buffer` over?

Comment: It's worth noting that C structures are hard to align with raw protocol structures and you're often better off having `read_uint16n` or `read_int64` type functions to extract values from a raw buffer. C structures can and will be padded arbitrarily by your compiler which can seriously mess up using them as raw buffers.

Comment: Updated the code to read into that structure.  After read `txTm_s` is always 1869574148.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the right value here? Do you need to skip over UDP headers since you're using raw packets? If you're raw, that's your job, the network stack is taking a hands-off approach.

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure of anything - classic staring at memory in C too long and can't even formulate attempts anymore.

Comment: Using raw sockets is complicating your solution here. [UDP is defined in RFC768](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768) if you need to know what the headers are. Perhaps you need to skip over both the IP and UDP headers.

Comment: When stuck on a problem like this be sure to use a tool like `tcpdump` or Wireshark to verify you're reading the correct values.